# Read Gmail in Android

Tags: android, gmail

I want to read the inbox of gmail and load the gmail to my app.Without going to gmail app i want to read the mail from my app itself.If anyone knows please share the idea with any sample app link also.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect your app to gmail. It wouldnt be running in your app but you could access gmail from your app.

Comment: i need to display the particular mails received from particular mail_id from my inbox to my app and show the list of mails in my app...Is it possible or not?

Comment: I dont believe its possible but i'm not an expert on the topic

Answer (score 0):

use a java client and connect https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1
filter, create, delete or whatever you want to do